# Paint invalid areas of a window using Win32 API and GDI

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

First, I'm new here, so hello world!

I'm working on a little lightweight controls library. Each control is an instance of a class named "GraphicElement", and doesn't have a handle. I created an event dispatcher and it works as expected but I struggle with the painting of my controls. They are stored in a tree, and I paint them as I go through this tree. I also use a back buffer to ensure the window's content doesn't flicker.

Everything works fine, but when I move one of the controls, this happens:

[image].

Of course, I can invalidate and repaint the whole window, which theoretically solves my problem, but I'd like to avoid doing so, especially when it's not necessary and for performance reasons.

Here's an example:

[image]

I'd like to move R2, then repaint the empty spot (I mean the old location of R2) without redrawing R4 and R5 (and maybe many others).

How to repaint the part of the background which "disappeared" ? Will I have to repaint the whole background, and so all my controls ?
I won't post all my code here because it's pretty long and it also handles other things like events, but as I said before, I draw my controls as I iterate through a tree, so there's nothing crazy in it.

Thank you in advance for your help, and sorry if I'm being not clear.

EDIT: Here's some code, but as I said before if I invalidate the client area of the window it works like a charm, but I want to avoid doing that.

This method ("render") is called when Windows sends a WM_PAINT message :

```
m_hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
m_bmpMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, m_rect.right - m_rect.left, m_rect.bottom - m_rect.top);
m_bmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(m_hdcMem, m_bmpMem);
m_background->predraw(m_hdcMem); // draws the client area, which is an instance of GraphicElement
BitBlt(hdc, m_rect.left, m_rect.top, m_rect.right - m_rect.left, m_rect.bottom - m_rect.top, m_hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(m_hdcMem, m_bmpOld);
DeleteObject(m_bmpMem);
DeleteDC(m_hdcMem);
```

And here's the method "predraw" :

```
draw(hdc); // draws the current control

for (std::vector<GraphicElement*>::iterator it = m_children.begin(); it != m_children.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->predraw(hdc); // "predraws" the other controls
```

Finally, when a control gets resized or moved, its area is invalidated using this function :

```
InvalidateRect(m_parentHwnd, lpRect, FALSE); // If I invalidate the whole window, my code works perfectly, but I'd like to know how to paint parts of my window
```

Comment: With no code we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: It's not much improved. Make a [mcve].

Comment: The code is really long and split into multiple files, it's going to be hard to compress it into a "minimal" example, but I'll give it a try...

Comment: You are on the right track, but you forgot to invalidate the part of the screen that R2 *used to be*. Otherwise that part of the screen won't redraw and consequently will still show leftover pieces of R2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. If I understand correctly, I will have to redraw that part of the background and R1 and R3. What if I set a background image ? Does that mean I will have to redraw it every time I move something on the window ? Or I can draw a part of it using BitBlt ? And how to detect the overlapping rectangles efficiently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "lightweight control that doesn't have a handle", but I guess they are simple C++ classes (and not true "controls) that must be drawn on the parent window's client area.

The "problem" is that the `WM_PAINT` message is a low-priority one, sent if the window has an invalid part in its client area, just before the application yields.

The documentation you should read first is: **[Painting and Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162759(v=vs.85).aspx)**

The implementation I would suggest, as I have used it quite a few times and works really well, is a combination of both methods:

- Process the `WM_PAINT` message (and the `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()` functions) to paint the whole client window (or a part of it, using the `rcPaint` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure, if a more "optimized" implementation is desired). Please note that the `WM_PAINT` message may be sent as a result of moving, resizing, bringing the window in foreground, or revealing a part of the window previously obscured by another one, that is due to user actions, in addition to programmatically invalidating the whole or part of it. So in response to this message you should draw the parent window and all the controls in their current position.
- Use the `GetDC()`/`ReleaseDC()` functions to draw only the part of the window affected by actions like adding, deleting, or moving a control. This kind of drawing takes place immediately, not waiting for the `WM_PAINT` message to be sent. You should fill the area previously occupied by the control and draw the control in its new position. You should not invalidate any part of the client area, as this would cause another `WM_PAINT` message to be sent.
- The control drawing functions should be taking a `HDC` parameter (among any others needed), so as to be usable by both drawing methods (the handles returned by either the `BeginPaint()` or the `GetDC()` functions).

I have used this technique to make image-processing applications (eg have the user selecting a part of the image and drawing/restoring the rectangle selected) and unattended monitor applications.

---

An alternative, simpler implementation (employing only "Painting" but not "Drawing") could be:

- When a control is resized or moved invalidate only the old and new areas occupied by the control.
- Processing of the `WM_PAINT` message generally as above, but it should be modified so as to fill only the rectangle in the `rcPaint` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure, and draw only the controls intersecting with the above rectangle.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot! Yes that's exactly what I meant, my controls are just plain C++ classes. I just removed InvalidateRect. I thought I shouldn't draw outside of the WM_PAINT message, but I didn't really understand the difference between WinAPI painting and drawing, now I do. But I don't know how to repaint the old area occupied by the control. Let's say my background is an image, how do I repaint the invalidated area? I thought of using BitBlt but it requires a handle to the source DC, which, in my situation, is the same as the destination DC (the background).

Comment: Not really, the destination DC is the window, while the source is the memory DC (and you already do this in your "render" method!). Also, what I seem to not understand is why you call predraw before BitBlt(). The controls should be drawn on top of the background. No? And what "predraw" is needed for anyway? Wouldn't just painting the background and then the controls (draw()) be enough?

Comment: And some performance tip, the bitmap, the mem DC and selecting into it, could be somehow cached, ie done only once (during some initialization phase) and stay for the application's lifetime, instead of creating (both), selecting etc and finally unselecting and destroying for every paint request. Then paint requests could only call BitBlt().

Comment: Drawing before BitBlt "prepares" the off-screen DC to be drawn later, that's how double buffering works, if I get it right. It's explained here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969905.aspx As you can see in the example all the "drawing" functions get called before BitBlt. I draw my controls on the off-screen DC, then I BitBlt the whole thing onto the background. Predraw is just a method I created to separate the drawing code and the for loop which I use to iterate over other controls.

Comment: You're right I should cache my bitmap. But I think I'll have to call CreateCompatibleBitmap anyway when the window gets resized, am I right?

Comment: Also, is it possible to paint only the old area occupied by the concerned control? I mean, if my background is an image, how can I repaint a part of it without redrawing everything?

Comment: By the way, I wanted to upvote your post, but I couldn't because I have less than 15 reputation points... so I thank you again for your precious help.

Comment: I just solved my problem caching a second bitmap which is a copy of the background. When a control gets moved, I copy the missing part of the background from the cached bitmap, then I fill that area of the window. I created this structure (which is very useful to store the data in a class) : `struct CachedBitmap
{
 HDC hdc;
 HBITMAP bmp;
};
`
Thank you again!

Comment: So, the double-buffering is only for avoiding flickering? OK, makes sense, only trouble you have to maintain the image yourself. If so, I think the best solution is Invalidate, and then use the `rcPaint` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure, creating and painting only this part in the bitmap, and of course BitBlt() only this. This way you have the system determining the area to be painted.